# split( "\r\n") is not splitting my string in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a webbrowser-based-app (client) and a java-based-program (server).
I am using the websocket-protocol for the connection between the client and the server. After a succesfull handshake, I am sending text-frames from my client to my server.

So I send the following String from my app (client):

```
{\r\n\"Name\":\"micheal\"\r\n}
```

When my java program gets the string (saved in String str), it printed the following on my eclipse-console:

```
{\r\n\"Name\":\"micheal\"\r\n}
```

Then my java-program calls a parser to parse the string str using this piece of code:

```
String delim = "\r\n";
// split content and put the elements in an array
String contentArray[] = str.split(delim);
//print the elements 
for(int i = 0;i<contentArray.length;i++){
    System.out.print(contentArray[i]+", "); 
}
```

But the program is not working like I want. the parser did not split my String according to my regular expression delim = "\r\n". I get an array containing one element, which is my original String:

```
{\r\n\"Name\":\"micheal\"\r\n}
```

I read some posts and tried to adapt my string, so that it works but it did not work.

What is the problem **in my case** and how can I solve it?

**Edit1:** I solved it. I send the following String from my client (webbrowse-based-App) :

```
{\r\n\"Name\":\"micheal\"\r\n}
```

and I use

```
delim= "\\\\r\\\\n"
```

But I have some questions.

can somoene explain me the cause for that problem?

**Why should I use delim= "\\\\r\\\\n" for  a string containing regex= "\r\n\"**. I do not understand it, since my parser is working fine when I put my string inside my code.

Comment: Are you sending \r\n or is there a real newline there? A newline, and string \r\n are different things.

Comment: If you are attempting to parse JSON with regex, **don't**. Just use a JSON parser.

Comment: well, I send a string containing \r\n  from the client. My Server should get this string (which contains \r\n) and and interpret it as newline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test it:

String delim = "\\\\r\\\\n";

Comment: Do you change `{\r\n\"Name\":\"micheal\"\r\n}` too?

Comment: firstly, I tried without changing {\r\n\"Name\":\"micheal\"\r\n} and using delim= "\\r\\n". It does not work. Then I send the following {\\r\\n\"Name\":\"micheal\"\\r\\n}. It does also not work

Comment: split(...) takes a regex, so just escaping the \ will not work you need to do this "\\\\r\\\\n"

Comment: @amitakCs  see last comment

Comment: solved: send the following String {\r\n\"Name\":\"micheal\"\r\n} and use delim= "\\\\r\\\\n"

Comment: @PK190000: I see your last comment and I answered you . I should not change it and I should use delim= "\\\\r\\\\n"

Comment: Can someone explain, why delim= "\\\\r\\\\n" works for me ?

Comment: @amitakCs \ is special character so you should print it with two \ and also becouse of regEx you should use \ for any \ then you have 4 \

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good to me, check if this (below) is what you want

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String str = "{\r\n\"Name\":\"micheal\"\r\n}";

        String delim = "\r\n";
        // split content and put the elements in an array
        String contentArray[] = str.split(delim);
        //print the elements 
        for (int i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i+": "+contentArray[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Tokens: "+contentArray.length);
    }
}
```

Output

```
0: {
1: "Name":"micheal"
2: }
Tokens: 3
```

If the situation is this

```
String str = "{\\r\\n\"Name\":\"micheal\"\\r\\n}";
```

use

```
String delim = "\\\\r\\\\n";
```

Comment: yes, it should work so. My parser is working fine, when I put the string inside my code. I tried it many times before. But when I get this string from my client, it does not work like I want.

Comment: I need the Ouput like you wrote in your answer. What should I send from my client. Which delim should I use?

Comment: can you post the output of System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.getBytes())); for your mysterious string?

Comment: I solved it using delim = "\\\\r\\\\n". I did not change my string

Comment: thats great, but as @nhahtdh already mentioned: If your input is JSON consider using a JSON parser instead of regex

Comment: actually,  I need a small parser, since I am making tests. Later I will use Json-Parser

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "\\r\\n" because '\' is unique character, not a escape.

or try System.getProperty("line.separator")