# Is stripping string by '\r\n ' necessary in Python?

Tags: python, string, whitespace, strip, cpython

In Java, it's necessary to strip with `\r\n`, e.g. [split( "\r\n") is not splitting my string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012113/split-r-n-is-not-splitting-my-string-in-java)

**But is `\r\n` necessary in Python?** Is the following true?

```
str.strip() == str.strip('\r\n ')
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters
>   removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of
>   characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument
>   defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a prefix or
>   suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped

From this [CPython test](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/test/string_tests.py#L775), `str.strip()` seems to be stripping:

```
 \t\n\r\f\v
```

**Anyone can point me to the code in CPython that does the string stripping?**

Comment: It's unnecessary unless you want to keep other whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for these lines?

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12222-L12247

```
#define LEFTSTRIP 0
#define RIGHTSTRIP 1
#define BOTHSTRIP 2

/* Arrays indexed by above */
static const char *stripfuncnames[] = {"lstrip", "rstrip", "strip"};

#define STRIPNAME(i) (stripfuncnames[i])

/* externally visible for str.strip(unicode) */
PyObject *
_PyUnicode_XStrip(PyObject *self, int striptype, PyObject *sepobj)
{
    void *data;
    int kind;
    Py_ssize_t i, j, len;
    BLOOM_MASK sepmask;
    Py_ssize_t seplen;

    if (PyUnicode_READY(self) == -1 || PyUnicode_READY(sepobj) == -1)
        return NULL;

    kind = PyUnicode_KIND(self);
    data = PyUnicode_DATA(self);
    len = PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(self);
    seplen = PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(sepobj);
    sepmask = make_bloom_mask(PyUnicode_KIND(sepobj),
                              PyUnicode_DATA(sepobj),
                              seplen);

    i = 0;
    if (striptype != RIGHTSTRIP) {
        while (i < len) {
            Py_UCS4 ch = PyUnicode_READ(kind, data, i);
            if (!BLOOM(sepmask, ch))
                break;
            if (PyUnicode_FindChar(sepobj, ch, 0, seplen, 1) < 0)
                break;
            i++;
        }
    }

    j = len;
    if (striptype != LEFTSTRIP) {
        j--;
        while (j >= i) {
            Py_UCS4 ch = PyUnicode_READ(kind, data, j);
            if (!BLOOM(sepmask, ch))
                break;
            if (PyUnicode_FindChar(sepobj, ch, 0, seplen, 1) < 0)
                break;
            j--;
        }

        j++;
    }

    return PyUnicode_Substring(self, i, j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially:

```
str.strip() == str.strip(string.whitespace) == str.strip(' \t\n\r\f\v') != str.strip('\r\n')
```

Unless you are explicitly trying to remove ONLY newline characters, `str.strip()` and `str.strip('\r\n')` are different.

```
>>> '\nfoo\n'.strip()
'foo'
>>> '\nfoo\n'.strip('\r\n')
'foo'
>>> '\r\n\r\n\r\nfoo\r\n\r\n\r\n'.strip()
'foo'
>>> '\r\n\r\n\r\nfoo\r\n\r\n\r\n'.strip('\r\n')
'foo'
>>> '\n\tfoo\t\n'.strip()
'foo'
>>> '\n\tfoo\t\n'.strip('\r\n')
'\tfoo\t'
```

This all seems fine, but note that if there is whitespace (or any other character) between a newline and the start or end of a string, `.strip('\r\n')` won't remove the newline.

```
>>> '\t\nfoo\n\t'.strip()
'foo'
>>> '\t\nfoo\n\t'.strip('\r\n')
'\t\nfoo\n\t'
```